# d3 single node moving with cursor repelling other nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I saw an example on a Mike Bostock video on youtube where he repelled nodes from a single node that moved with the mouse cursor.

I've tried to replicate this and put together something that works for all of 5s before it starts struggling and then stops altogether. JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hiwilson1/p6hxop7m/. Can anyone explain why this comes to a halt after such a short period of time?

```
function moveNode() {
    var m = d3.mouse(this);

    force.nodes()[0].x = m[0];
    force.nodes()[0].y = m[1];
}

function tick() {
    svg.selectAll(".node")
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) { if (i != 0) return d.x})
        .attr("cy", function(d, i) { if (i != 0) return d.y})
}
```

My best guess would be the problem has something to do with the tick event and mousemove event working hard and running concurrently, although I have other examples of the two working harmoniously.

Any help appreciated.

UPDATE: adding force.start() at the end of moveNode(), directly after manually influencing force.nodes()[0] coordinates has fixed it. Can anyone explain to me what that actually does?

Comment: I see the tick call stops ticking after 298 calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [D3 documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#start) (my emphasis):

> #### force.start()
>
> Starts the simulation; this method must be called when the layout is first created, after assigning the nodes and links. **In addition, it should be called again whenever the nodes or links change.**

You're not calling `start()` in the `tick` function, so the animation is simply ending gracefully. Simply add `force.start()` to the end of `tick()` and it should work fine.

[(updated jsfiddle here)](http://jsfiddle.net/p6hxop7m/1/)

Comment: Seems strange though. Feels intuitively like if I change the coordinates of that node the tick function should then just pick up those coordinates and move the node accordingly Would be nice to get a really thorough explanation of why we have to use force.start(). Thanks though.

Comment: @hwilson1 point 3 of my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30013792/2670182) to your previous question.

Comment: Thanks @Cool Blue - I took a look at force.nodes() pre force.start() and post force.start() and it's clear that x, y, px, py, index etc are all assigned when you use force.start(). I was working on the assumption these were assigned when you associated data with force but would've realised if I'd had a look in the console. Thanks.

Comment: @hwilson1 No worries mate... The best thing by far is to study the d3 code. It's daunting at first but a lot of it is documented in the guit hub repo and you can maintain your own local copy and add your own comments to lock in your learning. Oh, and maybe you could accept some of those answers I left for you ;)

Comment: Answers accepted, I'm comparatively new to stackoverflow (in terms of being active on here) so often forget to do that - gentle nudges always appreciated ;) thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
force.resume();
```

at the end of the moveNode function.

This continues the 'animation' in the jsfiddle you provided.

But I can't explain why, other than that is how it is done in the example here: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/collision.html